# spectral entropy as stock volatility

Tags: volatility, quants, fourier-transform

There are many way to capture to stock volatility and most common is `Beta`. But problem with `beta` this is difficult to select which benchmark to use.
Can `spectral entropy` be used for stock volatility?  The intuition is that higher the value of spectral entropy more knowledge about underlying function so less volatile is this and less value of spectral entropy more randomness so more volatile.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Beta is a measure of systematic risk, not of volatlity. Variance and standard deviation are typical measures of volatility.